# how to override css class style

Tags: php, css

I have a problem with Wordpress Theme.
I'm trying to put sidebar in header.. and because of sidebar class style it receives "colored" backround. if I will change it then all sidebars will have a change.

How I can override that style class only so a change will be only in a place I need it?

part of section in template page.php

```
<?php display_ca_sidebar( $args ); ?>
```

css section of sidebar

```
#sidebar ul li{width:298px;float:left; background:url(i/Modern/sidebar.jpg) left top no-repeat #83b1cd;  margin:0 0 19px 0;padding:0 0 10px 0; list-style:none; list-style-type:none;  border:1px solid #536867;}
```

I need to override "background"

Thanks for Help!

Comment: I don't know wordpress, but does it not allow you to edit html code? In that case you could just change the id of the sidebar to #sidebar2 and define fresh css. Sorry if I am sounding stupid here.

Comment: css section is in style.css

if I will insert in page.php file anything before <?php display....> any tag <div> <span> with any kind of style it doesn't do a right thing for me :(

Comment: This question is probably better suited for wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Give it an unique id and use that id as css selector.

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/faq/ you are in control of the HTML. So when you are creating the sidebar `div`, just give it a different class with which you can style that particular sidebar.

You shouldn't have to overwrite anything. When using `#sidebar`, you should try to use that ID for CSS that applies to all "sidebars", then use a specific class to make each sidebar appear the way you want. That gives you the ability to reuse classes and also create a default class, but you'll never have to worry about conflicts or overwriting things.

Comment: You can't add the class, the background doesn't show up or the old background shows up?

Comment: i don't want add anything.. i want to clear backroung .. make it "none".. and remove "border" but if i will clear it in style.css it will do it for all sidebars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you're trying to change the background of one element in a list of elements (which I'm guessing it is if it's inside li tags), then this may be of use:

```
#sidebar ul li:nth-child(2)
{
background:blue;
}
```

and replace the number two with whichever number you need to get your sidebar to work

hope that helps